# how to make the scale of a plot fixed in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I made two codes to run in Shiny/R but when I run them and change the parameters for growth and cost by sliding the bars, visually the graph does not seem to change. It does change because the numbers on the axis change instead but I would rather keep the numbers (scale of the graph) fixed and let the graph line move. Anybody could help me on making the scale of the graph fixed?

Thank you kindly.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Kost vrijwillige oppashulp"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Kies een waarde voor de groei"),
      sliderInput(
        "growth",
        "groei:",
        min = 0.01,
        max = 1,
        value = 0.025,
        step = 0.005
      ),
      helpText("Kies een waarde voor de kostprijs"),
      sliderInput(
        "price",
        "kostprijs:",
        min = 1,
        max = 3,
        value = 1.85,
        step = 0.05
      )

    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("graph"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    year <- 2016:2025
    growth <- 0.025
    price <- 1.85
    costcentra <- 33523.25
    totalhours <- c(1119784, rep(NA, 9))
    for (i in 1:9) {
      totalhours[i + 1] <- totalhours[i] + totalhours[i] * input$growth
    }
    cost <- totalhours * input$price
    centraOH <- c(53, rep(NA, 9))
    for (i in 1:9) {
      centraOH[i + 1] <- centraOH[i] + 2
    }
    totalcostcentra <- centraOH * costcentra
    totalcostOH <- cost + totalcostcentra
    plot(year,
      cost,
      type = "l",
      col = "red",
      lwd = 2)

    # Create a title with a red, bold/italic font
    title(main = "Cost of volunteer help",
      col.main = "blue",
      font.main = 4)

    # title(xlab="Year", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
    # title(ylab="Cost", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify axis limits with:

```
    plot(year, cost, type="l", col="red", lwd=2,ylim=c(1000000,5000000))
```

The axis limits will now always stay the same. However, this means your plot will not always fit within the plot window. Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
    plot(year, cost, type="l", col="red", lwd=2,ylim=c(1000000,max(5000000, max(cost))))
```

so that the limits will be between 1 and 5 million, unless the maximum value exceeds 5 million, in which case the y axis will adapt. Hope this helps.